# i want to validate if data is not exsist in database laravel 8

Tags: laravel

i want to validate data if data is not exsist in database on update case

my controller

```
public function update(Request $request )
{
    $no     = DB::table('member')->where('id',$request->id)->select('nokartu');
    $plat1  = DB::table('member')->where('id',$request->id)->select('nopol');
    $plat2  = DB::table('member')->where('id',$request->id)->select('nopol2');
    $data   = member::find($request->id);
    $data->nokartu  = $request->nokartu;
    $data->nama     = $request->nama;
    $data->paket    = $request->paket;
    $data->jenisk   = $request->jenisk;
    $data->tipe     = $request->tipe;
    $data->nopol    = $request->nopol;
    $data->nopol2   = $request->nopol2;
    $data->awal     = $request->awal;
    $data->akhir    = $request->akhir;
```

this my validate to check if data was not exsist in data base

```
if (!($no == $request->nokartu)) {
        if (member::where('nokartu', '=', $request->nokartu)->count() > 0)
        {
            $data=member::find($request->id);
            $produk['data'] = DB::table('produk')->get();
            return view('member.edit', ['produk'=> $produk],['member'=>$data])->withMessage( 'Kartu sudah dipakai');
        }    
    }
    
    $data->save();
    return redirect('/member')->with(['success' => 'Data berhasil di simpan']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a form request to validate the requests. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation.
It can be done by doing some thing like this

```
// Controller
public function update(UpdateModelRequest $request) {...}

// UpdateModelRequest
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
...
public function rules(): array
{
   return [
     'nokartu' => ['required', 'string'],
     'id' => ['required', 'int', Rule::exists('member', 'id)] 
}
```